# Stripe is charging twice

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe for payment.
I have created a customer Swapnil(cust_AAA) on stripe
Swapnil purchased a one time plan worth $149 for 12 monts it costs her $1788
Meanwhile in this time period she wants to upgrade her plan to 499 for 12 months that will cost her $5988
but as she has purchased it before expiry of previous plan than we are charging her $5988 - $1788 = $4200
This time she choose to be a recurring customer so, we have scheduled her next payment 12 months from now

Here!
I am facing issue:
When she switched from one-time to recurring I have charge her 4200
When I scheduled Subscription plan for next year She is being charged 5988 from stripe.
What should I do my customer to next subscription but I should not charged her anything now.
While upgrading any subscription in stripe it is charging complete price of that plan

Answer (score 0):

You need to charge more details of exactly how you are creating and then updating the subscription.

In general, when [updating subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#changing) the default behaviour will [apply prorations](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations) to credit for unused time within paid periods.

You might want to reach out to Stripe support with your specific customer/invoice/subscription example to have them help you understand why this happened, or investigate if something went wrong: https://support.stripe.com/contact